# Not passing values in a html form to a python cgi

Tags: python, forms, cgi

I have a Python .py cgi script that is working fine alone but not when I try to put new values in via a Form

Below you will see how it basically looks when working alone

In the script, myprogram uses the value of screen_name which is now **username1** in order to get details of **username1** and it is working fine

The problem comes up when I try to use a form to get info on other users like usernam2 or username3  etc

Here you will see details of this working script

........................

```
details = myprogram.show_user(screen_name='**username1**')

print "content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8"
print
print"<html><head></head><body>"
print (details['followers'])
print "<br/>"
print (details['friends'])
print "<br/>"
print (details['name'])
```

............................

As I mentioned above The problem comes up when I try to use a form to capture a different **username**

In my html form , via POST there is a field name called keyword in which the value of the field is called **username**  The Action on the form points to this .py program that is below

I want to use the value of the username captured in the Form in my script so when you write and submit the username value the .py script uses as screen_name the value in the Form

So if the form now has as keyword username2 or username3  then the .py script would need to change from 
details = myprogram.show_user(screen_name='**username1**')

to
details = myprogram.show_user(screen_name='**username2**')

or to

details = myprogram.show_user(screen_name='**username3**')
 depending on the value inserted in the Form

Below this is how I have tried to do it and does not work   It keeps returning the value of user instead of a new value inserted in the form
What I want is to give the screen_name the value found in the input of the Form, that could be username1, username2 etc etc

user is equal to the value found which was written in the form  and is what I try to do when I write user=form.getvalue(username)

When I run the script like below there is no error but the script does not take the value from the form it just executes and gives screen_name the value it now has instead of the one in the Form

The importance here is to have screen_name = to the value of what was written in the form

So I say screen_name = user  where user = form.getvalue('username')

BUt I need help because this is nort working

Thank you

Javier
............................

```
import cgi
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

user = form.getvalue('username')

details = myprogram.show_user(screen_name='user')

print "content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8"
print
print"<html><head></head><body>"
print (details['followers'])
print "<br/>"
print (details['friends'])
print "<br/>"
print (details['screen'])
```

........................................

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put the variable name in quotes.

```
details = myprogram.show_user(screen_name=user)
```

Comment: Could this fact that I get the same results of putting the variable name with or without quotes mean something ?

Comment: IT WORKED   I had some error in another part of the script, and after taking out the quotes IT WORKED nicely   Thank you @DanielRoseman